# Read from Cassandra and write to Cassandra (in chunks) using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, batch-processing, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to execute a large process in Spark, trying to avoid Spark Streaming.
I need to read from Cassandra, manipulate data and write to another Cassandra table.

I'm using a dataframe for the source table, with `dataframe.rdd`; I get a RDD to apply a map to manipulate the rows and then save the RDD to cassandra with `saveToCassandra`.

Spark reads all the data, apply the map and then writes all data. This causes a lot of HDD caching, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Is there any way to perform all operations (read, modify, write) in chunks, instead of reading the entire table and only then writing all the data?

My code:

```
val foo =  df.rdd.map { row =>
    val a = foo(row) //Transform row to scala case class
    function(a) //Return manipulated data
}

foo.repartitionByCassandraReplica(...).saveToCassandra(...)
```